# UITextView Subclass tap to didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITextView subclass that has an `NSIndexPath` property that is inside a `UITableViewCell`. When you tap on it, I'd like to be able to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Here's what I have:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
[theTextView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
singleFingerTap.delegate = self;

....

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    CustomTextView *theTextView = (CustomTextView *)touch.view;

    NSLog(@"%@", theTextView.indexPath);


    return YES;

}
```

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035061/select-tableview-row-programmatically), I may even have to break up my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` logic, which is fine. And I already know the index path of the view that was tapped.

What is the proper way to call this tableView method (or what `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` would do) from within the gesture recognizer method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8954530/927947). Basically when you call:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

the tableview doesn't fire the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` on the tableview's delegate, so in addition you are forced to directly call (And since you wrote the code in the delegate method there's no problem):

```
[tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

Also your passing `nil` for the action is really not how gesture-recognizers where mean to work:

```
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
```

Generally you would do something like this:

```
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
```

That basically tells the gesture recognizer to call the `tapRecognized:` method when it receives a tap. So basically to wrap it all up (I'm assuming this is in a `UITableViewController` or an object with a property named `tableView` as `UITableViewController`s have by default).

```
-(void)tapRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGR{
    // there was a tap
    CustomTextView *theTextView = (CustomTextView *)tapGR.view;
    NSIndexPath *path = theTextView.indexPath;
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do `X` both in response to a gesture and to a tap on a table view row, simply create a method `X` and call that from your gesture recognizer method as well as from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` table view delegate method.

Of course, theoretically,

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

would work, but I think calling the delegate method yourself is bad style to say the least.